# Visual Studio 2017- Visual Paradigm integration

Tags: integration, visual-studio-2017, visual-paradigm

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and I would like to integrate with Visual Paradigm 14.0.
I get a mistake: "Visual Paradigm Visual Studio Integration requires Standard Edition or above of Visual Studio"

Since with Visual Studio 2017 Community you can deeply customize the installation by explaining which technologies to install, I might have excluded some of the technologies needed to interact with Visual Paradigm.
Anyone could tell me what? Since the complete installation also requires more than 50 GB!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually Visual Paradigm IDE integration is available for ALL Editions starting from **[Visual Paradigm Community Edition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/editions/)**

However, the Feature- Code Engineering support is "STARTED FROM" the [Visual Paradigm Standard Edition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/editions/standard/). As IDE is mainly for performing coding, so the IDE integration only make sense when the code engineering capabilities are available.

[IDE Feature in Standard Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBHDf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a licence for visual paradigm (visual studio integration requires you to purchase a licence of [either standard or professional](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/shop/) )

Comment: From the official forum I learned that it just does not yet support Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: All editions of Visual Paradigm 14.1 support integration with Visual Studio 2017. And the features you have in the integration environment are subject to the [edition of Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/edition-comparison.jsp) you using.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the latest [Visual Paradigm v14.1 SP1](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/aboutus/newsreleases/vp141sp1.jsp) already supported integration with Visual Studio 2017. And the integration is supported by all editions of Visual Paradigm and all editions of Visual Studio. Of course the features you can access in integration environment is subject to the edition of Visual Paradigm you have.

[image]